# Create and edit a list of dataframes on the fly

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of several strings, and I need to create a list of identical dataframes from it.
The strings, for example, are a-d. The list should be

```
[1] xa
[2] xb
[3] xc
[4] xd
```

where each element is a dataframe. Each dataframe should have its columns named from another list (the column names are identical across dataframes)

```
strings <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
DFList <- list()
for (i in 1:4){
  DFList <- c(DFList,
              assign(paste0("x",strings[i]),
                     data.frame(matrix(0,ncol=5,nrow=0))))
}
```

doesn't work. It returns 4 dataframes, and a list of 20 elements (4 * 5 columns).

After they're created, I need to then be able to add rows to certain ones of those dataframes later in the script, which I also can't figure out.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replicate` or `lapply` with `setNames`

```
setNames(replicate(4, data.frame(matrix(0,4,5)), simplify=FALSE), paste0("x", strings))
```

The default column names of the data.frames are "X1","X2",etc.  So, if you have another list of names for the columns just wrap in another `setNames`, like `setNames(data.frame(...), otherNames)`.

The `lapply` syntax is pretty similar,

```
setNames(lapply(1:4, function(i) data.frame(matrix(0,4,5))), paste0("x", strings))
```